# How can I tell if a certain view (tile) has been defined in a Controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tiles, tiles2

Spring 3.0.5 + Tiles

Inside my controller I'm creating a new ModelAndView but a situation has come up where one company wants their own view.  Once this happens I can see this growing where other's want their own as well.

```
@RequestMapping(params="companyId")
public ModelAndView newCompanyView(HttpServletRequest request, String companyId) {
    // right here I'd like to check if the "companyABC" view is a defined tile
    // and if it is the send that back as a view and I can eliminate a bunch of if
    // checks. 
    if(companyId.equals("ABC")) {
        return new ModelAndView("companyABC", "vo", getCompanyVo());
    } else {
        return new ModelAndView("company", "vo", getCompanyVo());
    }
}
```

Is this possible and if so then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there really isn't a good way to do this unless you really want to dive head first into fiddling with view resolvers.  I don't have the time or the desire to try and figure it out but if someone smarter than I has some time I'd love to hear a solution.  Until then I'm just going to punt and have some IF checks for special companies.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be interested in Spring's [support for themes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-themeresolver), which can inherit from each other and fallback to a default.

Comment: already looked into spring's theme support but unfortunately the customer doesn't just want the page to look different, they want different functionality.  The page I need is almost a completely different page.  In fact I may just go down that road if something like I'm asking isn't possible.